# Submit Button run-time Error 13

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I can not figure out why I keep getting the run time error. I have place a "**" on the line giving me the error. I'm trying to create code for a "submit" button.

```
Private Sub Submission_Button()

For x = 2 To 1834

a = Sheets("INTERFACE").Range("E9:F10") 'this defines the feeder number'

b = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 1) ' this defines the feeder number in the data_entry sheet'

Dim dataentry As String

    dataentry = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 2)

    *if a = b Then*
        Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 3).SetValue (dataentry)

        MsgBox ("Submission Successful")

    End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: `a` is a range of cells, `b`is a single cell.  What do you mean by trying to see if they're equal?

Comment: the value is in merged cells that have that range (Merge and Center) and b is in 1 cell

Comment: I'm trying to tell excel to test if the values in those cells are equal then execute the task (copy a value in row x column 2 to row x column 3)

Comment: You are trying to see if the value held in `b` is equal to ALL the values held in `E9:F10`? Or are you trying to test if the value held in `b` is equal to ANY value in `E9:F10`? Or something else? Your code doesn't make sense as is. Your comments says "This defines the feeder number" but you have 4 cells in there. Which cell in that group defines the feeder number? Is this a merged cell, perhaps?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but since `a` doesn't change, set it outside of your `for` loop. Otherwise it gets reset (to the same thing) each iteration, which is expensive and superfluous.

Comment: I'm trying to test if the value held in b is equal any value typed in cells E9:F10 ( This is a merged cell so it only contains one value)

Comment: `a = Sheets("INTERFACE").Range("E9").value` reference a merged cell's value from the top left cell address.

Comment: I added all the fixes which fixed the rror but now its not executing the tasks, its not doing anything can any shed some light? see code

Comment: I made all the fixes and it fixed the erro but its not executing as intended helpPrivate Sub Submission_Button()

a = Sheets("INTERFACE").Range("E9").Value 'this defines the feeder number'

Dim dataentry As String

For x = 2 To 1834
        
b = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 1).Value ' this defines the feeder number in the data_entry tab'
  
    dataentry = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 2).Value
  
     If a = b Then
        Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 3).SetValue (dataentry)
        
        MsgBox ("Submission Successful")
      
    End If
    
    Next x
    
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>I'm trying to test if the value held in b is equal any value typed in cells E9:F10 ( This is a merged cell so it only contains one value)</sub>

Reference a merged cell's value from the top left cell address.

```
a = Sheets("INTERFACE").Range("E9").value
```

As per [JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill)'s comment this belongs outside the loop (as does `Dim dataentry As String`) and I don't believe that is an appropriate use of [.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Submission_Button()
    Dim dataEntry As String, x As Long, a As Variant, b As Variant

    a = Sheets("INTERFACE").Range("E9") 'this defines the feeder number'

    For x = 2 To 1834
        b = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 1) ' this defines the feeder number in the data_entry sheet'
        dataEntry = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 2)

        If a = b Then
            Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 3).Value = dataEntry
            MsgBox ("Submission Successful")
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!!! this worked!! I wish I could've came up with this on my own as the success would've been sweeter but I am glad you helped me. Thank you!!

Comment: ( @DarwinMendez - You can flag this as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (below the down arrow).)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this approach to verify all cells in the range for a match:

```
a = Sheets("INTERFACE").Range("E9:F10") 'this defines the feeder number'
b = Sheets("data_entry").Cells(x, 1) ' this defines the feeder number in the 

Dim x As Range
For Each x In a.Cells
  if x.value= b then
    Msgbox "Found!"
    Exit For
  end if
Next
```